# Why do I have to restart IIS Only then can the image be loaded when connect by new PC or new browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

Why do I have to restart IIS Only then can the image be loaded when connect by new PC or new browser.

[image]
before restart IIS
[image]
after restart IIS:
[image]

My code:
In Program.cs:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
NetworkCredential sourceCredentials = new NetworkCredential { Domain = "192.168.84.2", UserName = "sonphat", Password = "it@smcl2019" };
using (new NetworkConnection("\\\\192.168.84.2\\Public\\ITM\\SAPB1", sourceCredentials))
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.GetFullPath("\\\\192.168.84.2\\Public\\ITM\\SAPB1"))
    });
}
```

Comment: why cant create a virtual folder in iis and point to shared drive? so you can access it by relative path.

Comment: I suggest you could firstly using the F12 network to see what happened at clinet 404 or else error. Then I suggest you could try to go to the server to access the image directly inside the server side to see if this work well or not.